# Parameterize the LoginUrl in IdentityServer?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have been trying to add a parameter in the Login URL. E.g.

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/{culture}/account/login";
                });
```

Is it possible to have such types of parameterized URLs? Also, how would I pass this culture from my (JavaScript) client application? What other options do I have to retain this culture (e.g. as a query string parameter or route data)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass dynamic values from client application using client oidc externParam.
eg; for oidc-client library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client)

```
 // client side code

manager = new UserManager({
    authority: localhost:5000 ,
    client_id: xxx,
    redirect_uri: xx,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile .....',
    //etc add more settings you need
};);

//initialize connection with identity server
//send settings to authorize endpoint (localhost:5000/connect/authorize)
this.manager.signinRedirect(
    {
        extraQueryParams: {abc:1} // you can add any number of custom key: value pairs
    }
);
```

but now how to create dynamic options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl based on extraQueryParams received by identity Server at authorize endpoint?
Example:
I have two login pages login1 and login2; not on identity server but at some other url for instance
localhost:4200/login1
localhost:4200/login2

now based on the extraQueryParams received you can add show either of these login pages using AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator.

```
//server side code
//startup.cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator<YourCustomAuthorizeEndpointResponseGenerator>();

//make new class

public class YourCustomAuthorizeEndpointResponseGenerator : AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator //extending default res generator; you can rewrite also using IAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
{
    public YourCustomAuthorizeEndpointResponseGenerator(ISystemClock clock,
        ILogger<AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator> logger, IConsentService consent,
        IProfileService profile,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IdentityServerOptions identityServerOptions, // Will be auto injected by identity server; use this to override loginUrl
        )
        : base(clock, logger, consent, profile)
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value.ToString().Contains("abc=1"))
        {
            identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = localhost:4200/login1;
        }
        else
        {
            identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = localhost:4200/login2;
        }
    }
}
```

all redirection and callbacks will be taken care by identity server based upon the redirect_uri setting passed from client side.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this I managed to hack something that works. I used query string to pass the parameter but you could do it with url.

```
var paramName = "culture";
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                    if (context.Request.Path.Value?.Contains("/connect/authorize") ?? false && context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.Query[paramName].Count == 1)
                    {
                        var location = context.Response.Headers["Location"].ToString();
                        var tenant = context.Request.Query[paramName].ToString();
                        var newUrl = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(location, "tenant", tenant);
                        context.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
                    }
                });
```

I send the param from owin UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and you can add a parameter with

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = (a) =>
                    {
                        a.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("culture", "en");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
```

I am sure you could add the param to all other providers.
NOTE: Don't use this for any secure info just stuff that are cosmetic.